# Ui is getting hang after calling Alert in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

//
Here I am calling on alart function onPress on text field . 
On calling that fucntion I am trying to open alert and on confirm I am calling onther fucntion .
But its getting hang if I am calling "showAlert1()" . This function is getting call many times

```
   showAlert1 (code,name,version) {  
        console.log("data alaert abc", code,name,version);
        Alert.alert(  
            'Confirmation',  
            'Are you sure you want to migrate this tariff',  
            [  
                {  
                    text: 'Cancel',  
                    onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),  
                    style: 'Cancel',  
                },  
                {text: 'Proceed', onPress: () =>this.confirmTariffMigration(code,name,version)},  
            ]  
        );  
    }  

 confirmTariffMigration =(code,name,version) =>{
    console.log("hhhhdhhdhdhdhhdd",code,name,version);
    const objData={
        addofferingActionCode:'',
        offeringCode:'',
        offeringName:''
    }
    this.props.updateTariffMigration(objData)
    }
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<View style={{ marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5,marginTop:10,backgroundColor:'#f1f1f1' }}>
            { tariffMigrationData.map(
                (data, index) => {
                return (
                //  <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={this.showAlert1(data)}>
                  <View style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5 }} key={index}>
                    <Card>
                      <CardItem header style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-between', borderBottomColor: '#f1f1f1', borderBottomWidth: 1 }}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                          <View>
                            <RegularText text={`${data.offering.name}`} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} />
                            <SmallText text={` ID ${data.offering.code}`} textColor="grey" />
                          </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{
                          backgroundColor: 'blue',
                          borderRadius: 75, height: 25, paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingTop: 5
                        }} >
                          <SmallText text={'Proceed'}  onPress={this.showAlert1(data.offering.code,data.offering.version,data.offering.name)} textColor='white' />
                        </View>   
                      </CardItem>
```

Comment: I have done that also . but not working

Comment: sorry this is not working .. onPress{ () => this.showAlert1(...) if I am using this funcytion is nit getting call

Comment: <SmallText text={'Proceed'}  onPress={() => this.showAlert1(data.offering.code,data.offering.version,data.offering.name)} textColor='white' />

Answer (score 0):

```
when we want to pass params to props, here are two ways:

<TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this.showAlert1(data)}>
<TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={this.showAlert1.bind(this,data)}>
/////////////////////////////////////

<TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={this.showAlert1(data)}>
```